# Angular2 : After npm update, my app is broken

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, package.json

I have a problem with my angular 2/cli project.

I have done an update of my npm packages but after that, when I'm using ng serve, I get theses errors :

```
Time: 12752ms                                                                                                              

    chunk    {0} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.map (main) 45.3 kB {2} [initial] [rendered]                                           
chunk    {1} styles.bundle.css, styles.bundle.map, styles.bundle.map (styles) 20.6 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.map (vendor) 3.52 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule

ERROR in ./src/app/shared/guards/unauth-guard.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/src/app/shared/guards/unauth-guard.ts (16,8): Property 'take' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (/Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:116:15)
    at /Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:141:17
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 23:0-59
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./src/app/shared/guards/auth-guard.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/src/app/shared/guards/auth-guard.ts (17,8): Property 'take' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (/Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:116:15)
    at /Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:141:17
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 24:0-55
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./src/app/application/application.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'application.frame.component.html' in '/Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/src/app/application'
 @ ./src/app/application/application.component.ts 39:18-61
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./src/app/application/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dashboard.component.html' in '/Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/src/app/application/dashboard'
 @ ./src/app/application/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts 63:18-53
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./src/app/application/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dashboard.component.scss' in '/Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/src/app/application/dashboard'
 @ ./src/app/application/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts 64:17-52
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./src/app/application/campaign/campaign.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'campaign.component.html' in '/Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/src/app/application/campaign'
 @ ./src/app/application/campaign/campaign.component.ts 81:18-52
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./src/app/application/campaign/campaign.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'campaign.component.scss' in '/Users/nicolas/Desktop/Dilit/seller-app/src/app/application/campaign'
 @ ./src/app/application/campaign/campaign.component.ts 82:17-51
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Even if I return to my old package.json config, I can't build my project.

These is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "seller-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.53",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7-pre",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.4",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.7.6",
    "ng2-toastr": "^1.3.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.40",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.7.0",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.4.0",
    "protractor": "4.0.14",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.1.4",
    "webdriver-manager": "11.1.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to downgrade Typescript to 2.1.1

Comment: @IgorJanković I try that with "npm install" after but I've got exactly the same errors. I try to back to old angular-cli/typescript/angular-core, but nothing work.Thank for your help

Comment: Return package.json to the old one, delete node_modules folder and run npm install.

Comment: For several of the errors related to the components you wrote, you will have to fix the paths to the HTML and CSS files. The latest CLI doesn't like relative paths anymore. Most of the time you have to add a `./` in front of the files the errors say it cannot resolve.

Comment: Many thanks @R.Richards my app work again now.

Comment: Maybe it is not your problem but updating dependencies might lead to error in code (unexpected changes or unnotified changes inside), so for production mode `npm shrinkwrap` is recommened to use.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when upgrading TypeScript to 2.1.4. The error exists when downgrading to TypeScript 2.1.1. The error disappears when downgrading to TypeScript 2.0.8.